# Power BI merge query in SSAS Tabular 1400

Tags: merge, powerbi, tabular, m, compatibility-level

Hello guys,

In Power BI, I'm able to merge two tables easily because you can (even with csv files) add new queries and merge them in two clicks.

What I need is to reproduce the same merge in Tabular 1400. The thing is that the source tables are two CSV files located in different folders. I succeed making the merge in M language before the import.

Here are my tables
[image]

[image]

And here is the merge one[image]
So, as you can see it is working until there. But once I click on import, there is an error message saying that `The name 'Table2' wasn't recognized.  Make sure it's spelled correctly`

So it must be related to the M language behind the merge but for me it is correct. Here is the M language

`let
    Source = Table.NestedJoin(Table2,{"Name"},Table1,{"Name"},"NewColumn",JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded NewColumn" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Source, "NewColumn", {"Name", "Age", "Country"}, {"NewColumn.Name", "NewColumn.Age", "NewColumn.Country"}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded NewColumn",{"NewColumn.Name"}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Removed Columns",{{"NewColumn.Age", "Age"}, {"NewColumn.Country", "Country"}}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Renamed Columns",{{"Age", Int64.Type}})
in
    #"Changed Type"`

I'm a bit lost actually because for me the M language is good. Any idea how to figure it out ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I was using an old version of SSDT. I replace it with the 17.4 version and now I just have to right click on the table while importing and uncheck `Create New Table`. That way, Only one table will be imported and the other one will be available for a futur merge.

If you need more informations let me know.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need Table2 in your report, try unchecking `Enable load`. To achieve this rightclick the Table2 query in the Queries Pane. At least that's where it is in PowerBI.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately I can't find the enable load button on Tabular, maybe it simply does not exist... Still stuck then